# How to create a file in java without random numbers getting added to the filename and delete after use?

Tags: java, maven

I have to create a temp file in the /tmp directory the code that I am using is adding random numbers to the filename. I have to use the name of the file in order to do something. With the random number, I am not able to use that file. The code I wrote is :

```
File dir = new File("/tmp");
String prefix = "temp";
String suffix = ".txt";
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, dir);
```

After using the file with the correct file name I also have to delete it how can I do that?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Concatenating the number obtained to the file name? That's just String concatenation. Please clarify.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   Everytime the number generated is different. How can I write a general code to read from the temp file

Comment: You'd read and write to the File the same as you would read from any File object. Perhaps it's me, but I'm still not clear on your problem

Comment: You have a variable `tempFile` that you can use to read from and write to the file. Why do you care how the file is called? The only thing I could think of would be to read the file from some other program or in a different run of the program, but this should not be done anyway because it is a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the File again, you can store the path of the file to be accessed at another time.

You can get the absolute path file using:

```
tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

To answer your question about deleting the file after you are finished using it, you can either use the `detete()` or `deleteOnExit()` methods of File.

Answer (score 0):

If your code needs a *predictable* filename, and you want that file to be cleaned up automatically when the program ends, don’t use a temp file (they have a random name - it’s just how they work) but rather just use [`deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) with a regular file:

```
File file = new File("some/filename.ext");
file.deleteOnExit();
```